# Finite summation with binomial coefficients, $\sum (-1)^k\binom{r}{k} \binom{k/2}{q}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I came across the following finite sum involving (generalized) binomial coefficients:

$$ 2^q \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k} \binom{k/2}{q} (-1)^k .$$

Putting this into Mathematica gives me:

$$ (-1)^q 2^{r-q} \left( \binom{2q-r-1}{q-1} - \binom{2q-r-1}{q} \right) $$

and I'm interested in how could this solution be derived. There seems to be some binomial coefficient magic going on which I don't understand.

So far I have made very little progress, I noticed that the $2^q \binom{k/2}{q} = \frac{1}{q!} \prod_{i=0}^{q-1} (k-2i)$ -term looks a bit like a double factorial but this didn't get me very far. There also seems to be a lot of identities for sums involving $ \binom{r}{k} (-1)^k $ but I haven't found anything useful for this case.

Comment: @GrigoryM If you are working on this one I will not attempt it.

Comment: @Marko tomorrow (or later) — maybe; if you have time now — please just go ahead

Comment: @GrigoryM you are right, question corrected

Comment: off the top of my head, something like http://math.stackexchange.com/a/609202/ should work (but finding a bijective proof would be, perhaps, more challenging)

Comment: Mathematica might know the "WZ-method". You could learn about that or - probably more accessible - generating functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *I am a Bear of Very Little Brain, and long proofs Bother me*, let me post slightly shorter version of essentially the same proof.

$2^q\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k\binom rk\binom{k/2}q$ is the coefficient of $z^q$ in the expansion of $(1-\sqrt{1+2z})^r=\left(\frac{-2z}{1+\sqrt{1+2z}}\right)^r$.

Now we want to substitue $\sqrt{1+2z}$ by $1+w$. There is a purely algebraic lemma for this, but one way to establish it is to write this coefficient as a (complex) integral and apply the change of variables formula for integrals:
\begin{multline}
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res}
%\res\,(1-\sqrt{1+2z})^r\frac{dz}{z^{q+1}}=
\res\left(\frac{-2z}{1+\sqrt{1+2z}}\right)^r\frac{dz}{z^{q+1}}=
(-2)^r\res\frac1{(1+\sqrt{1+2z})^r}\frac{dz}{z^{q-r+1}}=\\
(-2)^r\res\frac1{2+w}\frac{dw+w\,dw}{(w+w^2/2)^{q-r+1}}=
(-1)^r2^{2r-q-1}
\res\frac1{(2+w)^{q-r+1}}\frac{dw+w\,dw}{w^{q-r+1}}.
\end{multline}
(here $\res_z=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\epsilon}$, if you will; since $z=w+w^2/2$, $dz=dw+w\,dw$).

So we get a sum of two binomial coefficients (each multiplied by $(-1)^\cdots2^\cdots$) — that's the answer Mathematica gave you.

Comment: Is there like a book or an online resource that would thoroughly explain these representations of coefficients as complex integrals (residues)? I'm having bit of a hard time with those (not this one in particular, but in general).

Comment: @655321 I'm afraid I don't know a good reference...

Comment: @655321 though there is one example that is explained in detail in many books (e.g. in _Enumerative Combinatorics_): Lagrange inversion formula

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$.

- For $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, we have
  \begin{equation}\label{Wilf-Lemma2.2}\tag{1}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k/2}{m}
  =
  \begin{cases}
  0, & n>m\in\mathbb{N}_0;\\ \displaystyle
  (-1)^{m}n!\frac{[2(m-n)-1]!!}{(2m)!!}\binom{2m-n-1}{2(m-n)}, & m\ge n\in\mathbb{N}_0.
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
- For $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, we have
  \begin{equation}\tag{2}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{m}
  =
  \begin{cases}
  0, & n>m\in\mathbb{N}_0;\\\displaystyle
  (-1)^n\binom{n}{m-n}2^{2n-m}, & m\ge n\in\mathbb{N}_0.
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
- For $m\ge n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, we have
  \begin{equation}\tag{3}
  \sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k/2}{m}
  =(-1)^m\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}.
  \end{equation}

(A1) The proof of the identity \eqref{Wilf-Lemma2.2} can be found in Lemma 2.2 and its proof in the paper [1] below.

References

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.
2. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences (2022), in press; accepted on 24 January 2022; available online at https://dx.doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941 or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/358050501.

Comment: Could you provide a proof?

Comment: @user I will provide a suitable proof, please keep patiently. Not only this answer, but also several other conclusions have been proved in a draft of a manuscript of mine.

Comment: A detailed proof of this answer is the proof of Lemma 2.2 in "Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1."

Comment: I would suggest you to give the reference as the part of the answer rather than a comment. It would be also useful to  refer the particular page or the formula number in the manuscript.

Comment: @user I will publish all proofs in officially published papers, but not here. One of reasons is that these proofs are not short and independent.

Comment: I don't understand your reasons giving the reference in a comment rather than in the answer.

Comment: @user I told you the reasons above, but you didn't understand, I don't know why you didn't understand. I believe that, after reading the reference at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1, you would and should understand all. I mainly aim to pubulish papers in mathematical journals, but don't only aim to post answers here.

Comment: Then you can equally delete this answer. Without a proof it is of no use.

Comment: I don't think so. Currently their proofs are not suitable to directly post here. As you said, you didn't understand why. In my opinion, we shouldn't talk about what we don't understand.

Comment: If you do not understand such simple things the further explanations are useless. Have a nice day.

Comment: Have nice days, everyone.