# Help with binomial identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation

In my work, I was led to the following identity.  I would be grateful if someone could provide an easy proof.

Suppose $n, d, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $d \geq 0$.

$$
\sum_{j = 0}^d (-1)^{d-j} \cdot \binom{d}{k} \cdot \binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1} \cdot \binom{n-d}{j-k} = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       0 & : d \neq k\\
       0 & : n < 0\\
       1 & : 0 \leq n \leq d\\
       2 & : d < n
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

I've been to the wikipedia page on binomial coefficients, looking for useful identities to apply.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Many well-known identities seem applicable, but I don't know how to handle the way $j$ appears once in the top of one of the binomial coefficients, and once in the bottom.  The identity

$$
\sum_{k=q}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{q} = 2^{n-q}\binom{n}{q}
$$

has the moving variable in both places, but I do not see how to use this.

What I'm trying to avoid is proof by induction.  The context is, I need this identity for an example in a paper.  I don't want to get hung up on the example, but I'd like to include a full proof.

Comment: There is a $\dbinom{d}{k}$ in the sum that does not depend on $j$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, and I suppose you could pull it out of the sum.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [the approach described there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601940/binomial-identity-sum-binom2n12k1-binommk2n-binom2m2n/602688#602688).

Comment: Yes, I don't get the $2$ either.

Comment: Are $d$ and $k$ supposed to be nonnegative?

Comment: @ccorn, That's a good idea, but I'm not sure how to handle the right-hand side in this context.  Does a Dirac delta function count as hypergeometric?

Comment: My suspicion on the proof is that the first step is rewriting the $\dbinom{n-j-1}{n-d-1}$ as $\dbinom{n-j-1}{d-j}$ (by the symmetry of the Pascal's triangle) and then using upper negation on this term (which removes the $\left(-1\right)^{d-j}$). This should yield an instance of Vandermonde convolution. However, the use of symmetry requires $n-j-1 \geq 0$, which I am not sure how to guarantee; probably this requires studying the other two binomial terms. If the OP clearly explains what set $d$ and $k$ live in, this will become a lot more doable.

Comment: @MorganRodgers The sum is usually zero,  so being a multiple of `\binom{d}{k}` is no problem.  The only time when the sum is nonzero is when d=k, and so the sum must be a multiple of 1; once again, no problem.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I take $n, d, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and use the same conventions as Mathematica for negative arguments.  (The reason I use the same conventions as Mathematica is that I checked my work in Mathematica.)

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon: I don't know much about Mathematica. Is it the convention that forces the recursion at the cost of symmetry, or the convention that forces symmetry at the cost of the recursion?

Comment: What is the convention for $d = k = -1,\  0 \le n$? Most conventions interpret sums over $j=0$ to $-1$ to be 0, where your identity produces 2 instead.

Comment: @will Ok, negative $d$ is confusing me, too.  Are all the conventions clear when $d$ is nonnegative?  I am editing to add the assumption that $d \geq 0$.

Comment: I don't see how you get 2 when $d=k=0<n$...

Comment: @darijgrinberg's suggestion is carried out [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/summingBinomialCoefficients.htm#Identity_4:_Minus_k_in_the_top_index), with $l\rightarrow n-1$, $m\rightarrow n-d-1$, $s\rightarrow n-d$, $n\rightarrow k$.

Comment: Your value $2$ seems to be wrong. For instance, for $n=1$, $d=k=0$, the result is $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculation with small values of $n,d,k\geq 0$ shows the following is valid

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{d}(-1)^{d-j}\binom{d}{k}\binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1}\binom{n-d}{j-k}
> =
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad 0\leq k=d<n\\
> 0&\qquad \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> \tag{1}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** It's easy to prove the special case $k=d<n$. In order to show that the expression is zero *otherwise* we use techniques known as *formal residual calculus for power series*. They are based upon [Cauchys residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and were introduced by *G.P. Egorychev* ([Integral Representation and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821845128)) to compute binomial identies.

We start with the easy one

> **Case: $0\leq k=d<n$**
>
> If $k=d$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{d}&(-1)^{d-j}\binom{d}{k}\binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1}\binom{n-d}{j-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=k}^{d}(-1)^{d-j}\binom{d}{k}\binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1}\binom{n-d}{j-k}\\
> &=(-1)^{d-d}\binom{d}{d}\binom{n-d-1}{n-d-1}\binom{n-d}{0}\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>
> This proves the first part of (1).

Recall that a binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is zero if $k<0$ or $n<k$. We observe in (2) the the index $j$ of  the rightmost binomial coefficient $\binom{n-d}{j-k}$has to be greater or equal $k$ otherwise the summand contributes zero. So, the lower bound of the index $j$ is $k$.

We also note that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n-d-1}{n-d-1}$ is equal to $1$ only in the case $n-d-1\geq 0$ which means $d$ less than $n$ and the easy part of (1) is shown.

We also see that $\binom{d}{k}$ is zero if $d$ is less than $k$. So, the only case which remains is

> **Case: $0\leq k<d$**
>
> We use the residue notation and write e.g.
>   \begin{align*}
> \mathop{res}_z\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+z)^{n}}{z^{k+1}}\mathop{dz}\tag{3}
> =[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
> \end{align*}

In fact we will use only two aspects of this theory:

Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^j$ be a *formal power series*, then

- Write the binomial coeffients as *residuals* of corresponding *formal power series*

\begin{align*}
\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{A(z)}{z^{j+1}}=a_j\tag{4}
\end{align*}

- Apply the *substitution rule* for formal power series:

\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j\mathop{res}_{w}\frac{A(w)}{w^{j+1}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

> \begin{align*}
> \binom{d}{k}\sum_{j=k}^{d}&(-1)^{d-j}\binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1}\binom{n-d}{j-k}\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{d}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{d-j}\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^{n-j-1}}{z^{n-d}}
> \mathop{res}_{u}\frac{(1+u)^{n-d}}{u^{j-k+1}}\tag{7}\\
> &=(-1)^d\binom{d}{k}\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n-d}}
> \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{1+z}\right)^j \mathop{res}_u\frac{(1+u)^{n-d}u^k}{u^{j+1}}\tag{8}\\
> &=(-1)^d\binom{d}{k}\mathop{res}_{z}\frac{(1+z)^{n-1}}{z^{n-d}}
> \left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{n-d}\left(\frac{-1}{1+z}\right)^k\tag{9}\\
> &=(-1)^{d+k}\binom{d}{k}\mathop{res}_{z}(1+z)^{d-k-1}\\
> &=(-1)^{d+k}\binom{d}{k}[z^{-1}](1+z)^{d-k-1}\tag{10}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $(1+z)^{d-k-1}$ has not a non-zero power of $z^{-1}$, the expression (10) is zero. This proves the second part of (1)

*Comment:*

- In (7) we extend the upper limit of the sum without changing the value since we are only adding zeroes and we rewrite the binomial coefficients using residues according to (3) and (4)
- In (8) we do some rearrangements to prepare for the substitution rule
- In (9) we apply the substitution rule according to (5)

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon:Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. Best regards,

Answer (score 5):

Substitute $r=d-j$ and use upper negation followed by Vandermonde's Identity:
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\sum_{j=0}^d(-1)^{d-j}\binom{d}{k} \binom{n-j-1}{n-d-1} \binom{n-d}{j-k}
&=\binom dk \sum_{r=0}^d(-1)^r\color{blue}{\binom{n-d-1+r}{n-d-1}}\binom{n-d}{d-k-r}\\
&=\binom dk \sum_{r=0}^d(-1)^r\color{blue}{\binom{n-d-1+r}r}\binom{n-d}{d-k-r}\\
&=\binom dk \sum_{r=0}^d(-1)^r\color{blue}{\binom{d-n}r(-1)^r}\binom{n-d}{d-k-r}\\
&=\binom dk \sum_{r=0}^d\binom{d-n}r\binom{n-d}{d-k-r}\\
&=\binom dk \binom 0{d-k}\\
&=\begin{cases}1\quad \text{if}\quad d=k \\0\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}\qquad$$
as $$\binom 0{d-k}=\begin{cases}1\quad \text{for}\quad d-k=0\\ 0\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice solution. Nevertheless the status of $n$ should be mentioned. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer - Thanks for the comment and upvote. Please feel free to edit the solution as suggested.

Comment: How do you get $\dbinom{n-d-1+r}{r} = \dbinom{n-d-1+r}{n-d-1}$ ? The symmetry of binomial coefficients holds when the "numerator" is nonnegative, but is $n-d-1+r$ necessarily nonnegative here?