# How to prove this summation formula?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, induction

Mathematica is able to calculate the following sum:

\begin{align}
 &\sum_{k,l=0}^{n,m}\frac{(-1)^{n+m-l-k}(2m)!(2n+1)!(2 )^{2k+2l}}{(2k+1)!(2l)!(n-k)!(m-l)!}(k+l)!  \nonumber\\
 =&\frac{(-1)^{m+n}2^{2m+2n+1}}{\pi(2n+1-2m)}\Gamma(m+\frac 1 2)\Gamma(n+1+\frac 1 2)  \nonumber\\
 =&\frac{(-2) ^{m+n}(2m-1)!!(2n+1)!!}{(2n+1-2m)}
 \end{align}

(The last step is just a way of re-writing it in terms of double factorial.)
I tried proving it (without putting in too much effort, however) but was not succesful. 
Do you have hints how this should be approached (or even full solutions)? 
I tried complete induction but ended up at a point where I would have had to prove a slightly less difficult summation formula.

Comment: The Wilf-Zeilberger method would be able to prove this using a computer algorithm. Thus, proving this by hand is like solving sudoku.

Comment: There is a [thread with an example of the WZ method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601940/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We  consider the identity  in the form
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k,l=0}^{n,m}\frac{(-1)^{n+m-l-k}(2m)!(2n+1)!2^{2k+2l}}{(2k+1)!(2l)!(n-k)!(m-l)!}(k+l)!=\frac{(-2) ^{m+n}(2m-1)!!(2n+1)!!}{2n+1-2m}
\end{align*}

> We divide both sides by $(-2)^{m+n}(2m-1)!!(2n+1)!!$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(2m)!(2n+1)!}{2^{m+n}(2m-1)!!(2n+1)!!}\sum_{k,l=0}^{n,m}\frac{(-4)^{k+l}(k+l)!}{(2k+1)!(2l)!(n-k)!(m-l)!}
> =\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2n+1-2m}}
> \end{align*}
>   We start with the left-hand side and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\frac{(2m)!(2n+1)!}{2^{m+n}(2m-1)!!(2n+1)!!}\sum_{k,l=0}^{n,m}\frac{(-4)^{k+l}(k+l)!}{(2k+1)!(2l)!(n-k)!(m-l)!}\\
> &\qquad=\frac{(2m)!!(2n)!!}{2^{m+n}}\sum_{l=0}^m\frac{(-4)^l}{(2l)!(m-l)!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-4)^k(k+l)!}{(2k+1)!(n-k)!}\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad=m!n!\sum_{l=0}^m\frac{(-4)^l}{(m-l)!l!l!}\binom{2l}{l}^{-1}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-4)^k}{2k+1}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\frac{(k+l)!}{(n-k)!k!k!}\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=\sum_{l=0}^m(-4)^l\binom{m}{l}\binom{2l}{l}^{-1}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-4)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\binom{k+l}{l}}
> \end{align*}
>
> The equality of the last line with $\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2n+1-2m}}$ is given in *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932)*.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the identity $n!=n!!(n-1)!!$
- In (2) we use $(2n)!!=2^nn!$

Comment: Thanks a lot - this really shows the benefits this page has. I also learned new methods from the different solutions in your linked post.

Comment: @Gesbesgue: You're welcome! :-) You might also be interested to take a somewhat closer look at the comments of my answer. It explicitly states two somewhat advanced representations of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ as integral and as residue.

Comment: Thanks again @Markus, I studied them today :)

Comment: @Gesbesgue: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think simple induction will work. I have reduced it to the identity
$$ 1 = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{(-4)^{k+j}(k+j)!(n)!(m)!(2n+1-2m)}
{(2k+1)!(2j)!(n-k)!(m-j)!} $$
for all $n\ge 0, m\ge 0$. The [Wilf-Zeilberger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair)
method could prove this but it is not satisfying to me.

Comment: A solution to this MSE post is available. The most relevant provided by Marko Riedel in this *[related MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932)*.