# Prove that $\sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{l}^2 (x+y)^{2l} (x-y)^{2(n-l)} = \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l} \binom{2(n-l)}{n-l} x^{2l}y^{2(n-l)}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

This problem derives from an expression of probability in random walk. I hope to

> prove that 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{l}^2 (x+y)^{2l} (x-y)^{2(n-l)} = \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{2l}{l} \binom{2(n-l)}{n-l} x^{2l}y^{2(n-l)}
> \end{equation*}

It seems quite right, I verified this equation from $n=1$ to $6$ without any idea to prove it.

This equality is found by @Sangchul Lee.

Comment: Hey, cool, this generalizes a famous identity (for $x = y = 1$). Could the same argument (rewrite $\dbinom{2l}{l}$ as $\left(-4\right)^l \dbinom{-1/2}{l}$) work?

Comment: Yes, I‘ve tried to add the $R.H.S$ up for $n$ from $0$ to $\infty$, then it suffices to prove that \begin{equation*}  \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty} \tbinom{n+m}{n} ^ 2 (x+y)^{2n} (x-y)^{2m} = (1-4x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} (1-4y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \end{equation*} But I have no idea how to deal with the $L.H.S$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RHS is the coefficient of $z^{2n}$ in the product between
$$ \sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{2l}{l}(xz)^{2l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2 z^2}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad  \sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{2l}{l}(yz)^{2l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y^2 z^2}} $$
i.e. the coefficient of $z^{2n}$ in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-4x^2 z^2)(1-4y^2 z^2)}}$.
 In the LHS we may recognize a [Legendre polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html):
$$ P_n(t)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{l}{n}^2(t+1)^l (t-1)^{n-l} $$
hence the given identity turns out to be a consequence of the following identity, about the generating function for Legendre polynomials:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}t^n P_n(x) $$
which can be proved through Rodrigues' formula or Bonnet's recursion formula.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It gives me an urge to study orthogonal polynomials :)

Comment: Beautiful proof through Legendre Polynomials and Generating function. Thanks for your work!

Comment: @SangchulLee: you know what they say, *once you go Legendre, you never go back*.

Answer (score 4):

We seek to verify that

$$\sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2 (x+y)^{2l} (x-y)^{2n-2l} 
= \sum_{l=0}^{n} {2l\choose l} {2n-2l\choose n-l} 
x^{2l}y^{2n-2l}.$$

Now we see on the LHS that the  powers of $x$ and $y$ always add up to
$2n$ and the exponent on $x$ determines the one on $y.$ Extracting the
coefficient on $[x^q][y^{2n-q}]$ we obtain

$$\sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2
\sum_{p=0}^q {2l\choose p} (-1)^{2n-2l-(q-p)} {2n-2l\choose q-p}
\\ = \sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2
\sum_{p=0}^q {2l\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} 
[z^{q-p}] (1+z)^{2n-2l}
\\ = [z^q] (-1)^q \sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2 (1+z)^{2n-2l} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {2l\choose p} (-1)^p z^p.$$

We  may extend  $p$ to  infinity  because with  $p\gt q$  there is  no
contribution to $[z^q]$, getting

$$[z^q] (-1)^q \sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2 (1+z)^{2n-2l} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} {2l\choose p} (-1)^p z^p
\\ = [z^q] (-1)^q \sum_{l=0}^{n} {n\choose l}^2 (1+z)^{2n-2l} 
(1-z)^{2l}
\\ = [z^q] (-1)^q [w^n] (1+w(1-z)^2)^n (1+w(1+z)^2)^n
\\ = [z^q] [w^n] (1+w(1-z)^2)^n (1+w(1+z)^2)^n.$$

Re-write this as

$$[z^q] [w^n] ((w(1+z^2)+1)^2 - 4 w^2 z^2)^n
\\ = [z^q] [w^n]
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 2^{2p} w^{2p} z^{2p}
(w(1+z^2)+1)^{2n-2p}
\\ = [z^q] 
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 2^{2p}  z^{2p}
[w^{n-2p}] (w(1+z^2)+1)^{2n-2p}
\\ = [z^q] 
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 2^{2p}  z^{2p}
{2n-2p\choose n-2p} (1+z^2)^{n-2p}.$$

We observe at this point that we  get zero here when $q$ is odd, which
agrees  with the  target formula.   We are  thus justified  in putting
$q=2l$ to get

$$[z^l] \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 2^{2p}  z^{p}
{2n-2p\choose n-2p} (1+z)^{n-2p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p} (-1)^p 2^{2p}
{2n-2p\choose n-2p} {n-2p\choose l-p}.$$

Note that

$${n\choose p} {2n-2p\choose n-2p} {n-2p\choose l-p}
= \frac{(2n-2p)!}{p! \times (n-p)! \times 
(l-p)! \times (n-l-p)!}
\\ = {l\choose p} \frac{(2n-2p)!}{(n-p)! \times 
l! \times (n-l-p)!}
= {l\choose p} {2n-2p\choose n-p} {n-p\choose l}.$$

Re-indexing we get for the sum

$$(-1)^n 2^{2n} \sum_{p=0}^n {l\choose n-p} {2p\choose p}
{p\choose l} (-1)^p 2^{-2p}
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} \sum_{p=0}^n  {2p\choose p}
(-1)^p 2^{-2p} [z^{n-p}] (1+z)^l 
[w^l] (1+w)^p
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^l [w^l]
\sum_{p=0}^n  {2p\choose p}
(-1)^p 2^{-2p} z^p (1+w)^p.$$

We  may  once  more  extend  $p$  to  infinity  because  there  is  no
contribution from  the sum term  to the coefficient  extractor $[z^n]$
when $p\gt n,$ obtaining

$$(-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^l [w^l]
\sum_{p\ge 0}  {2p\choose p}
(-1)^p 2^{-2p} z^p (1+w)^p
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^l [w^l]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z(1+w)}}
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^l [w^l]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z+wz}}
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^{l-1/2} [w^l]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+wz/(1+z)}}
\\ = (-1)^n 2^{2n} [z^n] (1+z)^{l-1/2} 
{2l\choose l} (-1)^l 2^{-2l} z^l \frac{1}{(1+z)^l}
\\ = (-1)^{n-l} 2^{2n-2l} {2l\choose l}
[z^{n-l}] \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z}}
\\ = (-1)^{n-l} 2^{2n-2l} {2l\choose l}
{2n-2l\choose n-l} (-1)^{n-l} 2^{-(2n-2l)}
\\ = {2l\choose l} {2n-2l\choose n-l}.$$

This  is the  claim. Credit  goes to  the Egorychev  method which  was
presented here in formal power series notation.

Comment: (+1) This is quite a work! Thank you for contributing to a combinatoric solution. I will give it a read when my work is done.

Comment: Thank you for presenting this interesting problem.

Comment: It's unbelievable that you've proved it by combinatoric method. I think I should study it meticulously. Thank you.

Comment: M. Scheuer recently proposed and solved a problem that uses a similar technique at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/).

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate answer.** We keep the preliminaries and
start with the contribution from $w$ being

$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w(1-z)^2)^n (1+w(1+z)^2)^n.$$

Now put $v=w/(1+w(1-z)^2)$ so that $w=v/(1-v(1-z)^2)$
and $dw = 1/(1-v(1-z)^2)^2 \; dv$ to get

$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} (1-v(1-z)^2)
\frac{(1+4vz)^n}{(1-v(1-z)^2)^n}
\frac{1}{(1-v(1-z)^2)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}}
\frac{(1+4vz)^n}{(1-v(1-z)^2)^{n+1}}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n {n+p\choose n} (1-z)^{2p}
4^{n-p} z^{n-p} {n\choose p}.$$

Observe that

$${n\choose p} {n+p\choose n}
= \frac{(n+p)!}{p! \times (n-p)! \times p!}
= {2p\choose p} {n+p\choose n-p}.$$

We obtain

$$(-1)^n \sum_{p=0}^n {2p\choose p} {-2p-1\choose n-p}
(-1)^p (1-z)^{2p}
4^{n-p} z^{n-p}
\\ = (-1)^n [w^n] \frac{1}{1+w}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {2p\choose p} (-1)^p (1-z)^{2p} 4^{n-p} z^{n-p}
(1+w)^{-2p} w^p.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor
in $w.$ Continuing,

$$(-1)^n 4^n z^n [w^n] \frac{1}{1+w}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {2p\choose p} (-1)^p (1-z)^{2p} 4^{-p} z^{-p}
(1+w)^{-2p} w^p
\\ = (-1)^n 4^n z^n [w^n] \frac{1}{1+w}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1-z)^2 w /(1+w)^2 /z}}
\\ = (-1)^n 4^n [w^n] \frac{1}{1+wz}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1-z)^2 w /(1+wz)^2}}
\\ = (-1)^n 4^n [w^n]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+wz)^2+(1-z)^2 w}}
\\ = (-1)^n 4^n [w^n]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+w}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+wz^2}}.$$

Now here we see that there are no odd order coefficients in $z$ and we
may put $q=2l$. Extracting the coefficient we get

$$[z^{2l}] (-1)^n 4^n [w^n]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+w}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+wz^2}}
\\ = [z^l] (-1)^n [w^n]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4wz}}
\\ =  (-1)^n [w^n]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4w}} {2l\choose l} (-1)^l w^l
\\ =  (-1)^n {2l\choose l} (-1)^l
{2n-2l\choose n-l} (-1)^{n-l}
\\ = {2l\choose l} {2n-2l\choose n-l}.$$

This is the claim.