# Prove the following by two different methods, one combinatorial and one algebraic

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Reading through my textbook I came across the following problem, and I am looking for some help solving it. I am asked to prove the following by two different methods, one combinatorial and one algebraic. If I could get help with either or both it would be great, thanks!

Prove that this identity is true,

$$\binom{n}{k} -\binom{n-3}{k} =\binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-2}{k-1} + \binom{n-3}{k-1}$$

Comment: I have tried to use pascal identity but got stuck, and I am not sure about the combinatorial approach

Comment: @jh123 for the combinatorial approach Pascal's identity is the right path. Hint: use it thrice

Comment: @Joe could you show me how this is done?

Comment: I'll point you in the right direction. so start with nCk. via pascal, we have nCk = (n-1)Ck + (n-1)C(k-1). The second expression on the right hand side shows up in what we're trying to reach, but the first term, (n-1)Ck, does not. What would happen if we used Pascal on that expression as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repeatedly, use the identity (Pascal's Identity), namely
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$
Note that 
$$
\left(\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)-\binom{n-2}{k-1}-\binom{n-3}{k-1}-\binom{n-3}{k}
$$
equals
$$
\binom{n-1}{k}-\binom{n-2}{k-1}-\binom{n-3}{k-1}-\binom{n-3}{k}
$$
which equals
$$
\binom{n-2}{k}-\binom{n-3}{k-1}-\binom{n-3}{k}
$$
which equals
$$
\binom{n-3}{k}-\binom{n-3}{k}=0
$$
as desired.

Comment: thanks for this, this would be considered algebraic?

Comment: @jh 123 Yes. I would classify it as algebraic.

Answer (score 14):

Combinatorial:  Rearrange to $${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-2\choose k-1}+{n-3\choose k-1}+{n-3\choose k}$$

Choose $k$ objects out of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.  This is counted by LHS.  We can also partition such choices into four parts:

(a) $1$ is the smallest item in our set of $k$.

(b) $2$ is the smallest item in our set of $k$.

(c) $3$ is the smallest item in our set of $k$.

(d) Our set of $k$ contains none of $\{1,2,3\}$.

The four terms of the RHS count just these four cases.

Comment: thanks for this complete combinatorial proof!

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Put $\binom{n-3}{k}$ to the other side and collect terms.

> This way we obtain starting with the right-hand side
>   \begin{align*}
> &\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\color{blue}{\binom{n-3}{k-1}+\binom{n-3}{k}}\\
> &\qquad=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\color{blue}{\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k}}\\
> &\qquad=\color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}}\\
> &\qquad=\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: could you show me how this is done?

Comment: @jh123: answer extended

Answer (score 5):

The following  algebraic approach is some sort of overkill  and for  curiosity only.  We use the *coefficient of* operator  $[x^n]$     to  denote  the coefficient  of  $x^n$  in  a  series. This  way  we   can  write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^n
\end{align*}

> We start with the left-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-3}{k}}&=[x^k]\left((1+x)^n-(1+x)^{n-3}\right)\\
> &=[x^k]\left((1+x)^3-1\right)(1+x)^{n-3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=[x^k](x^3+3x^2+3x)(1+x)^{n-3}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The right-hand side admits the representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\binom{n-1}{k-1} }&\color{blue}{+ \binom{n-2}{k-1} + \binom{n-3}{k-1}}\\
> &=[x^{k-1}]\left((1+x)^{n-1}+(1+x)^{n-2}+(1+x)^{n-3}\right)\\
> &=[x^{k-1}]\left((1+x)^2+(1+x)+1\right)(1+x)^{n-3}\\
> &=[x^{k-1}]\left(x^2+3x+3\right)(1+x)^{n-3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[x^k]\left(x^3+3x^2+3x^2\right)(1+x)^{n-3}}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Since (1) and (2) coincide the claim follows.

Comment: @jh123: You're welcome. Thanks for the credit.

Comment: Overkill? Isn't this just generating functions?

Comment: @qwr: It's a kind of overkill since there are many other different variants where a solution can be derived. *[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/a-nice-but-somewhat-challenging-binomial-identity/2394634#2394634)* is an example where generating functions are essential. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> **Combinatorial proof  without words**:
>
> [image]
>   \begin{align*}
> \hline
> \end{align*}

**Or with some words:**

We consider the lattice paths of length $n$  from $(0,0)$ to $(k,n-k)$ consisting of $(1,0)$-steps and $(0,1)$-steps  only. The number of these paths is $$\binom{n}{k}$$ since we have to choose precisely $k$ $(1,0)$-steps out of $n$ steps.

> The identity
>   \begin{align*}
> \underbrace{\binom{n}{k}}_{\color{blue}{\textbf{P}}} -\underbrace{\binom{n-3}{k}}_{\color{red}{\textbf{Q}}} =\underbrace{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}_{\textbf{R}} + \underbrace{\binom{n-2}{k-1}}_{\textbf{S}} + \underbrace{\binom{n-3}{k-1}}_{\textbf{T}}
> \end{align*}
>   is valid, since
>
> - the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $\color{blue}{P=(k,n-k)}$ which do not pass $\color{red}{Q=(k,n-3-k)}$
>
> is the same as the number of paths from $(0,0)$ which go either
>
> - to $R=(k-1,n-k)$
> - or $S=(k-1,n-1-k)$
> - or $T=(k-1,n-2-k)$.
>
> *Note:* Each of the paths to $R,S,T$ can be uniquely extended to $P$ via a $(1,0)$-step followed by zero, one or two $(0,1)$ steps.

Answer (score 2):

For the combinatorial approach, consider the following problem: you have the first $n$ numbers $1,\dots,n$ and you want to pick $k$ of them in such a way that you pick at least one of $1$, $2$ or $3$. On the LHS you compute the total number of choices minus the choices in which you don't pick any of $1$,$2$ or $3$. On the RHS you sum over the cases in which you pick $1$ and another $k-1$ numbers, or $2$ and another $k-1$ numbers but NOT $1$, or $3$ and another $k-1$ numbers but NOT $1$ and $2$. So you have two different ways of counting the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Combinatorial: $k$ people are selected from a group of $n$, $1\le k\le n-3$. Choose $1$ leader and then the remaining $k-1$ people for a total of $k$ people chosen.  There are $3$ candidates to choose from for the leader that each have a unique different level $1,2$ or $3$.  Once a candidate is selected, no candidate with a lower level may be selected for the remaining $k-1$ people.

LHS: All possible selections minus the case where none of the candidates are selected.

RHS: Level 1 candidate chosen + level 2 candidate chosen + level 3 candidate chosen.