# Calculate sum with binomials using generating functions

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

How would you calculate this sum using generating functions? I have tried a lot of things but cannot seem to get the right solution which should even contain $\sqrt{π}$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: You can just factor the $(-1)^n$ outside the sum, so it doesn't change the problem.  Do you mean to have it be $(-1)^i$? edit: Made irrelevant by edit, but not sure about OP's intent

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$ to write the sum as a convolution so that you can factor.

Comment: The previous comment yields that this sum is the coefficient at $x^n$ in $(1+x)^n(1-x)^n=(1-x^2)^n$. The rest should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes, the edit is right.

Comment: Looks like the sum is $$\begin{cases}(-1)^{n/2} \binom{n}{n/2}&\text{if $n$ is even},\\0&\text{if $n$ is odd}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: If the sum is as I claimed, then the generating function is $1/\sqrt{1+4z^2}$.

Comment: @RobPratt I've added an answer below.

Comment: A generalization is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582722/prove-sum-k-0r-binomnk-binomnr-k-left-1-rightk-left-1-righ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the coefficients of the product of polynomials (or power series) is given by the convolution of the coefficients of each series:  $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k \right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right) x^n$$
Thus since $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2  = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}  \binom{n}{n-k} 
\end{align*}

is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} x^k\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k\right) = (1-x)^n(1+x)^n = (1-x^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-x^2)^k$$

which is $0$ if $n$ is odd, otherwise $\binom{n}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}$, corresponding to the $k = n/2$ term in the above sum.

Comment: Looks good. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

A slight  variation of the   theme.  It  is convenient to use the *coefficient   of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2(-1)^k}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\binom{n}{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k[x^{n-k}](1+x)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^n](1+x)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^n](1+x)^n(1-x)^n\tag{5}\\
> &=[x^n](1-x^2)^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^{n/2}\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}[n\equiv0 \operatorname{mod}  2]}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we apply  the *coefficient of*   operator  according   to (1).
- In (4)  we  apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $[x^n]$ using *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)*.

Comment: So is the advantage of this approach that you can start computing without initially recognizing a convolution?  Or just that it looks prettier because you can do it in one string of equations?

Comment: @JairTaylor: For this problem both approaches are well suited and its just a matter of convenience which one to use. The benefit of the *coefficient of* operator is  better seen  in  somewhat more complex  problems  like  *[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/a-nice-but-somewhat-challenging-binomial-identity)*. In  fact  a mastership using these techniques can be found *[here](https://www.amazon.com/-/de/dp/0821845128)*.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That is indeed a scary looking identity :)

Answer (score 1):

A tricky one. Remember that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n - k}$, so:

$\begin{equation*}
   \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2
     = \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n - k}
\end{equation*}$

This is a convolution,
we can write it as the coefficient of $z^n$ in the product:

$\begin{align*}
   [z^n] \left( \sum_k \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k z^k \right)
            \cdot \left( \sum_k \binom{n}{k} z^k \right)
     &= [z^n] (1 - z)^n (1 + z)^n \\
     &= [z^n] (1 - z^2)^n \\
     &= \begin{cases}
           (-1)^{n/2} \binom{n}{n / 2} & n \text{ even} \\
           0                & n \text{ odd}
        \end{cases}
\end{align*}$