# How may one solve problems over expressions like $(2+px)^6$ without the binomial theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, contest-math, alternative-proof, binomial-theorem

A friend of mine posed a problem on a mathematics discord server.

> The coefficient of the $x^2$ term in the expansion of $(2+px)^6$ is $60$. Find the value of the positive constant $p$.

I immediately thought of employing the binomial theorem, as what was required, actually. But, I decided to do another method, which led me to the question of how we can solve such problems *without* using the binomial theorem.

How can we solve this question without the binomial theorem or newton's method?

---

**My Attempt:**

*Lemma*: $$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ac)x+abc.$$

Note that $$(2+px)^6=(2+px)^2(2+px)^2(2+px)^2$$ $$=((px)^2+4px+4)((px)^2+4px+4)((px)^2+4px+4)$$ Therefore, in the lemma, substitute $x\mapsto (px)^2$ and $a,b,c\mapsto 4px+4$. It follows $$(2+px)^6=(px)^6+12(px+1)(px)^4+48(px+1)^2(px)^2+64(px+1)^3.$$ We can ignore the first two terms since they contain no strict $x^2$ coefficient. Thus, upon expanding $$48(px+1)^2(px)^2+64(px+1)^3$$ it follows the coefficient of $x^2$ is $240p^2$. $$240p^2=60\tag{$p>0$}$$ $\therefore p=\frac 12$.

Comment: You write _The coefficient of the expansion of $(2+px)^6$ is $60$_.  Do you mean _The coefficient of the $x^2$ term in the expansion..._?

Comment: @AndrewChin yes, that's what I meant. My apologies - that lack of specificity presumably stumped many users, lmao.

Comment: You are basically explicitly expanding $(a+b)^6$, though you are doing it in two steps - first the cube $(a+b)^3$ and then substituting $(a^2, 2ab+b^2)$ for $(a,b)$ to square it. Of course you are also leaving out any terms you don't need along the way.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Eh, you are right, so imma just delete this question altogether. I mean, I don't suppose it contributes to anything, and perhaps I merely overreacted at the somewhat unorthodox method with which I approached this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This implicitly uses the Binomial Theorem (**edit: no it does not**), and calculus, but anyway...

Let 
$$p(x)=(2+px)^6=a_0+a_1x+60x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^3).$$

Differentiate twice:

$$\begin{align}
p'(x)&=6(2+px)^5\cdot p=a_1+60\cdot 2x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)
\\ \Rightarrow p''(x)&=6p\cdot 5\cdot(2+px)^4\cdot p=120+\mathcal{O}(x)
\end{align}$$

Evaluate at $x=0$:

$$30p^2\cdot 2^4=120\Rightarrow p^2=\frac{1}{4}\Rightarrow p\underset{p>0}{=}+\sqrt{\frac14}=\frac12.$$

Comment: That is very neat! (You may have made a typo at the last part, but I understand what you mean :P) It doesn't *directly* use the binomial theorem but I never thought about differentiating to reduce the degree of $\mathcal O$. Thank you! You answered just in time too $-$ I was ready to delete my question, lol.

Comment: @MrPie it depends on how you prove that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$... I suppose it could be done with induction and so this is independent of the binomial theorem.

Comment: I'd just go with limits by first principles to prove that, upon differentiation, $x^n$ does indeed map to $nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MrPie how do you do that not using induction nor the binomial theorem?

Comment: Well for me, it's intuitive since nearly all the terms just become $0$ given $h\to 0$. You're right, it does use the binomial theorem, but it doesn't need to be used explicitly - though that's more or less a personal thing.

Comment: @mrpie I suppose you could argue that $(x+h)^n=x^n+nhx^{n-1}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ without the Binomial Theorem but I would just use induction.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three different methods. The first one is recommended, the others are just for fun and curiosity.

**Combinatorial approach:**

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. Here we are looking for a positive solution $p$ of
\begin{align*}
60=[x^2](2+px)^6\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Multiplying $(2+px)^6$ out we get a contribution to $x^2$ if and only if we select from two factors $2+px$ the term $px$ giving us $p^2x^2$ and taking from the other $4$ factors $2$ giving us $2^4=16$. Since we can select two factors from $(2+px)^6$ in $\binom{6}{2}$    ways, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{60}=[x^2](2+px)^6=\binom{6}{2}p^22^4=15p^2\cdot  16\color{blue}{=240p^2}
\end{align*}
from which $p=\frac{1}{2}$ follows.

**Algebraic approach:**

A somewhat cumbersome but simple approach is to iteratively work through the linear factors $2+px$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{60}&=[x^2](2+px)^6\\
> &=[x^2](2+px)(2+px)^5\\
> &=\left(2[x^2]+p[x^1]\right)(2+px)(2+px)^4\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(4[x^2]+4p[x^1]+p^2[x^0]\right)(2+px)(2+px)^3\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(8[x^2]+12p[x^1]+6p^2[x^0]\right)(2+px)(2+px)^2\\
> &=\left(16[x^2]+32p[x^1]+24p^2[x^0]\right)(2+px)(2+px)^1\\
> &=\left(32[x^2]+80p[x^1]+80p^2[x^0]\right)(2+px)\\
> &=160p^2+80p^2\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=240p^2}
> \end{align*}
>   from which $p=\frac{1}{2}$ follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (2)     and the following lines we determine the coefficients according to the rules from (1), i.e. 
  \begin{align*}
  &\left(a[x^2]+b[x^1]+c[x^0]\right)(2+px)=2a[x^2]+(2b+ap)[x^1]+(2c+bp)[x^0]
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we select the coefficients accordingly.

**Complex analytic approach:**

This variant shouldn't be taken too serious. It's just for fun and in fact based on the first method. We recall the *[residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)* which tells us  that integrating along a circle with radius one around the origin we have
\begin{align*}
[x^2](2+px)^6=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|x|=1}\frac{(2+px)^6}{x^3}\,dx
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{60}&=[x^2](2+px)^6\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|x|=1}\frac{(2+px)^6}{x^3}\,dx\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\left(2+pe^{it}\right)^6}{e^{3it}}\,ie^{it}\,dt\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(2+pe^{it}\right)^6e^{-2it}\,dt\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\binom{6}{2}2^4p^2\,dt\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\binom{6}{2}2^4p^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,dt\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=240p^2}
> \end{align*}
>   from which $p=\frac{1}{2}$ follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the substitution $x=e^{it}, dx=ie^{it}dt$.
- In (3) we note $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-kit}\,dt =0, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is due to Euler's identity $e^{2\pi i}=1$. So, everything vanishes in (3) besides the *constant* term.
- In (4)     we select the constant term in fact with the same considerations we used in the first approach.

**Note:** Another approach might be using *[shifted series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection#Multisection_of_analytic_functions)* in order to filter the wanted coefficient of $x^2$.

Comment: Wow, that is really efficient! I have never seen this method before, so thank you very much for showing this to me. It appears it can be widely applicable. +1 :)

Comment: @MrPie: You're welcome. Another application is e.g. when proving *[binomial identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559154/calculate-sum-with-binomials-using-generating-functions/3561359#3561359)*.

Comment: @MrPie: I've extended the answer somewhat.

Comment: That complex analytic approach.... I am gonna need a whole book and a half to grasp that XD