# Show that: $\sum_{l=0}^{m}(-1)^{m+l}4^{l-1}l{m \choose l}{2l \choose l}^{-1}{m+l \choose l}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^2$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

By observing  and alteration of the OP's [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384932/a-nice-but-somewhat-challenging-binomial-identity/2386135#2386135) we found this sum which is equivalent to the natural square number, $\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^2$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{m}(-1)^{m+l}4^{l-1}l{m \choose l}{2l \choose l}^{-1}{m+l \choose l}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}i^2\tag1$$

How can we prove $(1)?$

$$l{m \choose l}{2l \choose l}^{-1}{m+l \choose l}=\frac{m!}{l!(m-l)!}\cdot \frac{l!l!}{(2l)!}\cdot\frac{(m+l)!}{l!m!}=\frac{(m+l)!}{(m-l)!}\cdot\frac{l}{(2l)!}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{m}(-1)^{m+l}4^{l-1}\frac{(m+l)!}{(m-l)!}\cdot\frac{l}{(2l)!}\tag2$$

note that $$\frac{(m+l)!}{(m-l)!}\cdot\frac{l}{(2l)!}=\frac{(m+l)!(m+l+1)}{(m-l)!}\cdot\frac{l}{(2l)!(m+l+1)}=\frac{1}{B(m-l+1,2l+1)}\cdot \frac{l}{m+l+1}$$

$$\sum_{l=0}^{m}(-1)^{m+l}4^{l-1}\frac{1}{B(m-l+1,2l+1)}\cdot \frac{l}{m+l+1}\tag3$$

Where B(n,m) is the [Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We seek to evaluate

$$\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m+q} 4^{q-1} q {m\choose q} {2q\choose q}^{-1}
{m+q\choose q}.$$

We get from the binomial coefficients

$$\frac{m!}{(m-q)! \times q!}
\frac{q! \times q!}{(2q)!} \frac{(m+q)!}{m! \times q!}
= \frac{(m+q)!}{(m-q)! \times (2q)!}
= {m+q\choose m-q}.$$

Our sum becomes

$$\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m+q} 4^{q-1} q {m+q\choose m-q}
= [z^m] (1+z)^m
\sum_{q=0}^m (-1)^{m+q} 4^{q-1} q z^q (1+z)^q.$$

The coefficient extractor enforces the range and we find

$$[z^m] (1+z)^m
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^{m+q} 4^{q-1} q z^q (1+z)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{4} (-1)^{m+1} [z^m] (1+z)^m
\frac{4z(1+z)}{(1+4z(1+z))^2}
\\ = (-1)^{m+1} [z^{m-1}] (1+z)^{m+1}
\frac{1}{(1+2z)^4}.$$

This is

$$(-1)^{m+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^m}
(1+z)^{m+1} \frac{1}{(1+2z)^4}.$$

Now we put $z/(1+z) = w$ so that $z = w/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \;
dw$ to get

$$(-1)^{m+1} \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^m} \frac{1}{1-w}
\frac{1}{(1+2w/(1-w))^4}\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = (-1)^{m+1} \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^m}
\frac{1-w}{(1+w)^4}
\\ = (-1)^{m+1}
\left( [w^{m-1}] \frac{1}{(1+w)^4}
- [w^{m-2}]  \frac{1}{(1+w)^4} \right)
\\ =
[w^{m-1}] \frac{1}{(1-w)^4}
+ [w^{m-2}]  \frac{1}{(1-w)^4}
= {m+2\choose 3} + {m+1\choose 3}
\\ = \frac{1}{6} m (m+1) (m+2+m-1)
= \frac{1}{6} m (m+1) (2m+1) = \sum_{q=1}^m q^2.$$

This is the claim.